# Cannot read property 'CheckFrequency' of undefined

Tags: react-native, code-push, react-native-code-push

My team recently added CodePush to our React Native app, and while it works perfectly fine on the original local repository, when I pull the changes I get the error

> Cannot read property 'CheckFrequency' of undefined

This occurs after installing react-native-code-push and linking it properly. All answers I found for similar questions seemed to have this error when using Jest, but we are not using Jest and this error happens any time I run `react-native run-ios`

The code looks like this:

CodePush is imported

```
import codePush from "react-native-code-push";
```

And later in the same file, the error occurs on

```
let codePushOptions = {
  checkFrequency: codePush.CheckFrequency.MANUAL, // error here
  updateDialog: false,
  installMode: codePush.InstallMode.IMMEDIATE
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing import to

```
import * as CodePush from 'react-native-code-push';
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case that was because I didn't link the package properly.
once you link "react-native-codepush" properly (either automatic or using rnpm or manually) codePush won't be undefined.